# Is there a way to call a method on a Python object returned by a function?

Tags: python, oop, command-line, filesystems

So I'm building a command-line tutorial program of sorts in Python. Basically it emulates a terminal and walks you through different levels using shell commands. The way the original version worked is I caught anything entered and analyzed it for calls to the tutorial program if there weren't any I passed the command to the computer using os.system().

Unfortunately, since I wrote the tutorial to be of a *nix system, it does not work on Windows, since I included levels using vim and what-not. My plan was to rewrite the program, but rather than making calls to the system, I'd create a virtual filesystem. This includes to objects: directory and file. You can probably figure out what both of the objects are meant to be. The directory object would contain a list of its contents and this would act as the filesystem. I would then implement commands like cd, ls, pwd, and so-on.

The problem I have run in to is that when I return a containing directory or file from a directory object I'm not able to edit it in any way. I'll give you an example of my code.

*NOTE: There are likely bugs in the code as I cannot test it very well without fixing this issue
Also, the imports aren't necessary to the problems. The first one is a color class that lays out the codes for doing colored output and the second is a file that contains global variables.
I've removed the calls to these resources so that it will run on someone else's system*

```py
#from ..resources.colors import colors
#from ..resources import variables as var

class Directory:
    # Basic constructor
    def __init__(self, name="", container=None, contents=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.container = container
        self.contents = contents
    
    # grabs index of contents by name
    def index(self, find):
        for i in range(len(self.contents)):
            if self.contents[i].name == find:
                return i
        return -1
    
    # Add something to the container
    def add(self, dirFile):
        # Check for duplicate names
        if self.index(dirFile.name) != -1:
            return False

        self.contents.append(dirFile)
        return True

    # Retrieve something that's in contents
    def get(self, neededName):
        ind = self.index(neededName)
        if ind >= 0:
            return self.contents[ind]

    # Returns true if it has at least one sub directory
    def has_sub(self):
        for content in self.contents:
            if type(content) == Directory:
                return True
        return False
    
    # Iterates through, looks for slashes and goes to subs (recursion, ooooh!)
    def get_sub(self, path=""):
        if not self.has_sub() or path == "":
            return self
        
        pathSplit = path.split("/")
        nextDir = self.index(pathSplit[0])
        
        if nextDir >= 0:
            return self.contents[nextDir]
        
        pathSplit.pop(0)
        path = "/".join(pathSplit)
        return self.get_sub(path)


        
            

    # ============== Shell Commands ==============

    # List all contents in directory
    def ls(self):
        for content in self.contents:
            if type(content) == Directory:
                #print(colors.fg.blue + content.name + colors.reset + "\t", end="") This is the code wih the colors class
                print(content.name + "\t", end="")
            else:
                print(content.name + "\t", end="")
        print()

    # Delete file by name:
    def rm(self, toDelete):
        ind = self.index(toDelete)
        if ind >= 0:
            self.contents.pop(ind)
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    # Make new dir
    def mkdir(self, name=""):
        if name:
            self.add(Directory(name))
            
        
## Current test
di = Directory("Test")
di.mkdir("one")
di.mkdir("two")

di.get_sub("one").mkdir("test")

di.ls()
di.get_sub("one").ls()
```

The current output is:

```
one  two  test
one  two  test
```

But the output should read:

```
one two
test
```

For some reason when I call:

```py
di.get_sub("one").mkdir("test")
```

It changes di rather than the object returned by get_sub()

Any help is much appreaciated! Let me know if there's anything else I should provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of pointers I think I can give you. The first is, probably most appropriately, to answer your primary question:

*It changes di rather than the object returned by get_sub()*

This is likely because no matter how things work out, has_sub() will eventually resolve to a subdirectory with no further directories in. This will result in this clause becoming true:

```
        if not self.has_sub() or path == "":
            return self
```

`if not self.has_sub` will evaluate true and return `di`. It'll always be `di` as your recursive routine always calls methods on `self` which is `di`. I hope that makes sense!

In terms of the second pointer I can give you, maybe I can ask a couple of questions regarding your test-case which might assist with some discover and though processes:

```
1: di = Directory("Test")
2: di.mkdir("one")
3: di.mkdir("two")

4: di.get_sub("one").mkdir("test")

5: di.ls()
6: di.get_sub("one").ls()
```

1. In line one you create `Test`, then add in (2) and (3) new (I suppose) subdirectories. However, looking at mkdir in your Directory implementation, these don't actually get created. Perhaps look at [os.mkdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir) and consider whether you need to worry about existing directories. [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) might also be your friend here...
2. Have a good look at what you're returning. If you `return self` you're returning the reference to the object you called the method on. If you chain a second method call to that (in your case) it will still be `di` that you call it on.

I think you'll have a lot of fun implementing this if you first start looking first looking into [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path) as a module then consider some of the additional os functions like mkdir mentioned above. Also consider that [os.getcwd()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) and [os.chdir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) might be of interest.

I really hope this helps. :-)

Comment: Ohhhh. The first part opened my eyes massively. I shouldn't be using recursion, I should call that objects get_sub() method instead, not sure if that's still considered recursion.

And I don't actually want the directories to get created, I want it to just live in the program, for compatibility reasons.



Do you mind detailing your second point more? If I fix the recursion issue it will call on a different object right? Assuming a different object is returned.

Thank you very much! I'll implement the recursion change tomorrow.

Comment: No it wouldn't be recursion on a different object, but that's cool: recursion works in more particular scenarios! You're basically building an object model of your filesystem if you represent it in objects which is definitely an interesting programming experiment. Best of luck. I'd really appreciate a tick from you if you've found the advice helpful. Nice one! :-) EDIT: cheers for the upvote Matt!!!

Comment: Sorry I have one more question. Wouldn't it run this if statement: "if nextDir >= 0:" in the example I provided? The code underneath that should return a different object right?

Comment: Good question! So the nextDir is a bit complicated (it's quite late here) but basically you're going to be returning -1 when the directory wasn't added to your di.contents by other calls. My best advice would be to put in some tactical `print` statements in both index() and get_sub() to help you trace what is going on. Remember too, once you return, nothing else in that method will run... I hope that helps!!!

Comment: Sounds good thank you! I'll take a deeper look tomorrow.

Comment: Another nice little trick for your index() method: you can write `if string in self.contents: ...` to look in your array ;-) [This is a good site for such references](https://python-course.eu/python3_sequential_data_types.php#Checking-if-an-Element-is-Contained-in-List)

Comment: Thank you. One last point then I'm gonna let you go. It turns out the issue is in mkdir(), when I add the Directories in using the contents bit in the constructor it works well. Thanks for your advice in all of this! I can keep you updated if you're interested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217518/discussion-between-jimcircadian-and-matt).